# Getting Type mismatch for my function

Tags: vbscript

I am getting an error message i.e.

```
Type mismatch: 'EMXWEB_IE_LAUNCH'
Line (1): "' ==============================================================================".
```

the function is 
**Option Explicit**

```
Public Function EMXWEB_IE_LAUNCH (dicArguments, sErrMsg)

Dim strVersion
Dim strExeVersion
Dim WshShell
Dim strEMXWebBrowserTitleBarText
Dim ie

Const strFunctionName = "EMXWEB_IE_LAUNCH"

Set ie = CreateObject( "InternetExplorer.Application" )
ie.Navigate "www.google.com"
ie.Visible=True

End Function
```

Could any one let me know where i am wrong and why i am getting this issue

Comment: Might not be related, but note that Functions should return a value `[Set] EMXWEB_IE_LAUNCH = SomeValue`. Otherwise turn it into a Sub?

Comment: any Idea i am getting " Error : Object Required :'SystemUtil'
code : 800A10A8

Comment: @SandyWilliams It's a little difficult to reproduce without knowing the end goal, what is it your trying to achieve with this function?

Comment: It is possible it is because you have defined a CONSTANT value (EMXWEB_IE_LAUNCH) with the same name as the FUNCTION?  Try renaming or removing the CONST declaration, because I don't see any purpose for it.

Comment: @SandyWilliams `SystemUtil` is a specific [Quick Test Professional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_QuickTest_Professional) object. If you are just using vanilla VBScript, you cannot use the SystemUtil object. The typemismatch error could reside in your function call. If the caller expects an object and you return `empty` or a primitive or if the caller expects a primitive and you return an object or `Nothing`, you get errors like this. But I am just guessing here because the code fragment you delivered is not sufficient to determine where the error comes from.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos is right - if it is in fact a function that you are supplying parameters to, it would be helpful to see how the function is called with what kind of data being supplied to it.  If all you're trying to do is open IE, it seems like there's a lot of code that can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I see errors like this in QTP with "line(1)" and it is sometimes related to a library being loaded previous to the library you have that function in. Missing an end of block or end of function in other library.

Maybe you can relate, but I also see this strange stuff when the QTP's rich text format it saves files in gets corrupted. you can try pasting the entire code into notepad to get plain text, then replace the entire QTP file with the text from notepad and save. This craziness has worked for me several times.